# linking node js and html

Tags: html, node.js, express

I am doing a project where i have a nodejs file called app.js and a html file index12.html. I have a mssql database, which i am querying through the .js file. I can display the result of query in the json format in the console. Now I need this data in the html file so I can draw a pie chart using it (for which I have used d3 js). I am using jquery to achieve that. But am not able to get the data into the html document.

I am very new to jQuery and

in the HTMl document, I am doing $.getScript("file"), I dont know if it is right

Here are the codes for

APP.JS AND INDEX12.HTML

```js
var http = require('http');                         //connect withb http
var sql = require('mssql');                         //connect with sql
var express = require('express');                   //connect with express
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var jQ = require('jquery');
env: {
    browser: true
}
//new beg.
var Connection = sql.Connection;
var Request = sql.Request;
//new end


var a; var recordSet;

var config = {
    server: '10.2.13.211',                          //my IP address - obtained through ipconfig       
    //server: '.',
    database: 'trialdb',                            //my table is within this server
    user: 'sa',                                     //windows authentication uses this username & password          
    password: 'admin123#',
    port: 1433                                      //deafault port number
};

function send404Response(response) {
    response.writeHead(404, { "Context-Type": "text/plain" });                  //display plain text          
    response.write("Error 404:Page not found");
    response.end();                                                             // we need to end each 
   
}

function loadEmployees() {                                                       // connection with ms sql table   
    
    var dbConn = new sql.Connection(config);
    
    dbConn.connect().then(function () {                                         //using promises instead of callbacks(onceconnect() is done), then go to then()
        
        var request = new sql.Request(dbConn);
        
        request.query("select * from list").then(function (recordSet) {         //once query is executed, then go to then()
          //  console.log(recordSet);
            a = recordSet[1].errors;
          //  return recordSet;
            dbConn.close();                                                      //close connection
        }).catch(function (err) {
            
            console.log(err);
            dbConn.close();
        });
    }).catch(function (err) {
        
        console.log(err);
    });

    
}


app.use(express.static('D:/d3 project/project_part1/project_part1/'));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../index12.html'));
    
});


app.get('/abt', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../startpage.html'));
});

function onRequest(request, response) {
    if (request.method == 'GET' && request.url == '/') {
        console.log("user made a request" + request.url);
        response.writeHead(200, { "Context-Type": "text/plain" });
        loadEmployees();
        setTimeout(function () {
            // response.write("here is some data");
            response.write("hiya" + a);
            response.end();
        }
            , 200);
    }
    else {
        send404Response(response); console.log('error 404');
    }
}



http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);                                          //creates a new instance of server when a request arrives as port 8888 & executes function onRequest() 
console.log('server will run on requset to port 8888');

var server = app.listen(8081);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Step 3 - Adding a Legend</title>
      <script> </script>
   
    <style>
   
  rect{                                              
   stroke-width: 2;                                          
   }  
  .legend{            
    stroke:black;
    opacity:1; 
    font-size: 12px; 
    }
    
  text{            
   font-family: sans-serif;
   font-size: 10px;
   fill:black;
   }
  
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <p>hi how  ru</p>
    <div id="chart"></div>
      <button type="button">Change Content</button>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="d3/d3.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
      <select id ="slctmodel"></select>
      <script>
          var dataset;
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    //$.getJSON("app.js", success = function (data) {
                    $.getScript("app.js", success = function (data) {
                  dataset = data;
                                     });

              setTimeout(function () {
              
                  /* dataset = [
                             { "module": "A", "errors": 50 },
                             { "module": "B", "errors": 120 },
                             { "module": "C", "errors": 10 },
                             { "module": "D", "errors": 200 },
                             { "module": "E", "errors": 27 },
                             { "module": "F", "errors": 25 },
                             { "module": "G", "errors": 40 }
                   ];*/
                  console.log(dataset);
                  var width = 1500;         //width and height of svg
                  var height = 1500;
                  var radius = 150;

                  var legendRectSize = 16;                           //rect size of the coloured box at index       
                  var legendSpacing = 4;                             //spacing b/n two small rect boxes       
                  console.log("hi1");
                  var color = d3.scale.ordinal()      //specific modules  pertain to specific colours independant of the no. of values in it
                        .domain(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", ])
                        .range(["#FFEBAA", "#EEAB79", "#955C52", "#BE4C60", "#B42E61", "#851362", "#5E0063"]);
                  var svg = d3.select('#chart')      // selecting the division with id 'chart' and appending svg and group to it.
                        .append('svg')
                        .attr('width', width)
                        .attr('height', height)
                        .append('g')
                        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + 850 + ',' + 250 + ')');

                  d3.select('#chart svg')         //within the chart svg,append text
                        .append("text")
                        .attr("x", 850)
                        .attr("y", 30)
                        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                        .text("PROBABILITY OF FAILURE IN MODULES");  //append text at the center

                  var arc = d3.svg.arc()         //create an arc of specified inner & outer radius
                        .innerRadius(30)
                        .outerRadius(radius);

                  var arcOver = d3.svg.arc()      //create an arcOver of specified inner & outer radius- when mouse moves over, arc changes
                        .innerRadius(20)
                        .outerRadius(radius + 30);
                  console.log("hi2");
                  var pie = d3.layout.pie()      //create pie (occurs acc to arc created), sector it according to values in dataset[]
                        .value(function (d) { return d.errors; })
                        .sort(null);       //sort-pie diagram is sorted

                  var path = svg.selectAll('path')    //add the arc to svg in the form of a path
                        .data(pie(dataset))
                        .enter()
                        .append('path')
                        .attr('d', arc)
                        .attr('fill', function (d, i) {
                            return color(d.data.module);
                        })
                        .attr("opacity", 1)
                        .attr("stroke", "black")
                        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                        .on("mouseenter", function (d) {   //as mouse enters, provide transition to arcOver
                            d3.select(this)
                          .attr("stroke", "black")
                          .transition()
                          .duration(1000)
                          .attr("d", arcOver)
                          .attr("stroke-width", 4)
                          .attr("opacity", 1)
                        })
                        .on("mouseleave", function (d) {   //as mouse leaves, provide transition back to arcOver
                            d3.select(this).transition()
                           .attr("d", arc)
                           .attr("stroke", "black")
                           .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                           .attr("opacity", 1);
                        })
                  console.log("hi3");
                  svg.selectAll('text')
                      .data(pie(dataset))
                      .enter()
                      .append('text')
                      .attr("transform", function (d) {  //add value at centroid of each arc
                          return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
                      })
                      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                      .text(function (d) {
                          return d.value;
                      })
                      .style("pointer-events", "none");



                  var legend = svg.selectAll('.legend')               //create a legend  ->set of colour boxes   
                        .data(color.domain())
                        .enter()
                        .append('g')
                        .attr('class', 'legend')
                        .attr('transform', function (d, i) {
                            var height = legendRectSize + legendSpacing;
                            var offset = height * color.domain().length / 2;

                            var vert = i * height - offset;
                            return 'translate(' + 250 + ',' + vert + ')';
                        });
                  console.log("hi4");
                  legend.append('rect')                                    //append legend in the form of rectangle
                        .attr('width', legendRectSize)
                        .attr('height', legendRectSize)
                        .style('fill', color)
                        .style('stroke', color);

                  legend.append('text')                                    //append text into legend
                        .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
                        .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
                        .text(function (d) { return d; });

                  console.log("hi5");
              }
          , 500);
          });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: express is not to serve only static files, you can serve almost anything.

Comment: if you are able to get the json data from  you node server via browser, but unable to get in your web app try implementing CORS in your node server.

Comment: besides, your question need to be more clear and specific with code snippets.

Comment: Hi, thank you for ur suggestions. I have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant get your requirement properly...but i think,

You have plot a pie chart based on data from database on a button click.

For this,

1. Make a service call to server on button click.
2. At server side retrieve data from DB and send it data back to client side.
3. At client side based on this data plot the graph.

I hope this may help you.

Comment: Hi, i am not able to make a service call , the rest is done, after the querying of database ..i have json data. I have the code to draw the pie. I am using jQuery to get values from my node js file to html file. But it doesnt seem to work

Comment: Hi, using jQuery ajax() you can make service request.

Comment: i can access a .json file and read its contents, but for that i will have to write the data retrieved from sql database into a .json file. I am trying to avoid the use of files

Comment: Hi, i wrote the data onto a http:// page & retrieved data from it using a jquery call. Instead of writint it on to a .json file on my pc , i wrote it on a web page & retrieved it and it eorks dynamically. Thank you